Deriving electrostatics problems using variational methods
I was thinking, as a new method, we can use the variational method to find σ (charge density) on the surface of a metal if total charge Q in put on it. My idea was that, the total electrostatic energy, U will be minimized, so I can write down that as an integral using σ which is unknown, and then use the Euler-Lagrange equation to minimize it. Doing so, and applying the equation of the metal surface, we will get an integral which includes (x’,y’,z’) and (x,y,z) and σ(x,y,z) and σ(x’,y’,z’) where r and r’ are two places on the surface. Then integrate the energy of two point charges over the surface. z’ and z could be eliminated using the surface equation. But still this integral will be a function of x’,y’,x and y which is not ideal. We expect something like an integral of x and y only to use the Euler-Lagrange equation. Can anybody give any ideas on how to carry on with this method? Thanks in advance!

Note that you can't freely vary $\sigma$;  you have to ensure that the amount of charge on the conductor is fixed.  Otherwise, your potential energy integral will be minimized by the configuration where $\sigma = 0$ everywhere.

The problem with this approach is that the energy integral is algebraic in $\sigma$;  the derivatives are not involved.  This means that the Euler-Lagrange equations are also going to be algebraic in $\sigma$;  you can't get an "interesting" differential equation out of Euler-Lagrange if there aren't any derivatives in the functional you're varying.  In the present instance, the Euler-Lagrange equations from your integral basically tell us that the surface is an equipotential and that charge is conserved.
To see how this works out in practice, let's try to extremize the energy, which can be written as a double integral:
$$
U = \frac{1}{2} \oint \oint \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}) \sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a \, d^2 a'.
$$
We also need to impose the constraint that the total charge on the surface is fixed:
$$
Q = \oint \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a.
$$
You can do this by varying the expression
$$
S = \frac{1}{2} \oint \oint \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}) \sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a \, d^2 a' + \lambda \left( \oint \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a - Q\right)
$$
with respect to the function $\sigma$ and the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$.
The variation of $U$ is
\begin{align*}
\delta U &= \frac{1}{2} \oint \oint \left(\frac{\delta \sigma(\vec{r}) \sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} + \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}) \delta \sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|}\right) \, d^2 a \, d^2 a' \\
 &= \oint \oint \frac{\delta \sigma(\vec{r}) \sigma(\vec{r}') }{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a \, d^2 a' \\
&= \oint \delta \sigma(\vec{r}) \left( \oint \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a' \right) d^2 a.
\end{align*}
(In the second step, we have simply relabeled $\vec{r} \leftrightarrow \vec{r}'$ in the second term of the previous step, which may have been the trick you were missing.)  Meanwhile, the variation of the Lagrange-multiplier term is
$$
\delta \lambda \left( \oint \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a - Q\right) + \oint \lambda \, \delta \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a.
$$
And so,
$$
\delta S = \oint \delta \sigma(\vec{r}) \left( \oint \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a' + \lambda \right) d^2 a + \delta \lambda \left( \oint \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a - Q\right)
$$
and the Euler-Lagrange equations are then
$$
\oint \frac{\sigma(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} \, d^2 a' =- \lambda \qquad \oint \sigma(\vec{r}) \, d^2 a = Q.
$$
But these are equivalent to saying that the surface is an equipotential and that charge is conserved.  We knew this already.

So the only thing that it tells us that we didn’t apply to the equations is that the surface is equipotential?

@MMD:  Yes, basically, since the charge-conservation requirement was put in "by hand" via the Lagrange multiplier.

I’m wondering what’s next to do? Write potential as an integral containing σ and setting the derivatives on the surface to zero?
